# Product over real interval? Is there a better way of putting this?

Tags: notation, infinite-product

In my amateur interest, I have arrived at this (nothing rigorous here at all):$$\prod_{a\in [1,2]} \prod_{b=0}^\infty f(a,b) \neq 0$$

For starters, there might be a more intuitive way about doing this. I want to be able to say that $f(a,b) \neq 0, a\in [1,2] \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $b\in \mathbb{R}$

- are there any identities that might simplify the two products?
- is it even worth specifying the product over a real interval? (For all real numbers between)

NOTE what the function $f$ is, is not what is important here, I'm looking for something more general.

Comment: Just to be clear is this what you want to express? $\forall a \in [1,2], f(a,b) \neq 0$. If you are unfamiliar with the notation, $\forall$ just means "for all" or "for every."

I don't quite see the point of the 'product.'

Comment: The point of the product is just an expansion of what you said ^ that could potentially be helpful

Comment: What does the cross denote in terms of sets?

Comment: $A \times B = \{(a,b) | a \in A, b \in B\}$

Comment: Yes, that is the innequality given, but what I'm trying to do is expand on that, maybe give something I can test for f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22597/discussion-between-mb7744-and-sam-walls).

Comment: This post seems related: [A question about $\prod_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{*}}{x}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39369/a-question-about-prod-x-in-mathbbrx)