# Sum of uncountable many positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The sum of an uncountable number of positive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers)

Suppose $f(x)>0$ for all real $x$, and $S$ is a set of uncountable many real numbers, how to prove that $\sum_{x\in S}f(x)=\infty$?

Alternately suppose $\sum_{x\in S}f(x)=k$, how to prove $|S|=N_0$ ?

Comment: hint: look at the cardinality of the set $\{x \in S| f(x) > 1/n\}$ and let $n\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_i=\{ x\in S : f(x)>1/i\}$ what is the cardinality of at least one of the sets $A_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the series $\sum_{x\in S_n}f(x)$ converges and consider the sets $S_n=\{x\in S\ |\ f(x)>1/n\}$.  Then each of these sets must be finite, because
$$
\sum_{x\in S_n}f(x)\geq\sum_{x\in S_n}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{|S_n|}{n},
$$
and $S=\cup S_n$.  Therefore if the series $\sum_{x\in S_n}f(x)$ converges, $S$ is countable (since it is a countable union of finite sets).

Comment: Why would the cardinality of $S_n$ be finite? Is it because $\sum 1/n$ is a lower bound on $\sum_{\alpha \in S} x_{\alpha}$ and we know infinite harmonic series diverges?

Comment: @Sun No, the harmonic series is irrelevant; see my edits