# Poles of Meromorphic Function has no accumulation points

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

**Let $f$ be a mermorphic function on a domain $G$. I want to show that the amount of poles and roots have no accumulation points in $G$.**

*Someohow this is related to [Can it be proved that a Meromorphic function only has a countable number of poles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962314/can-it-be-proved-that-a-meromorphic-function-only-has-a-countable-number-of-pole?rq=1) 
Now I only need to do it for the zeros.* I think because of the definition that the poles have to be isolated, I think it's not really provable.

Comment: Doesn't that post give you the answer? Poles are isolated singularities and zeros of a non-zero function are isolated. Any uncountable subset of the Complex plane has a limit point. So one can have at most countably-many .

Comment: It answers my question of course, but how do I write this down?

Comment: I would use something to the effect of " Any uncountable subset of the plane must contain a limit point ( e.g., by Weirstrass' thm) and poles are isolated and zeros of a non-zero analytic function are isolated, therefore the amount of poles and zeros of a non-zero analytic function are at most countable.

Comment: What is your definition of $f$ being meromorphic on $|z-a| < r$ ? If it is with the Laurent series then it is clear $a$ is not an accumulation point of poles of $f$.  If it is $f = \frac{g}{h}$ where $g,h$ are analytic, then the Taylor series of $g,h$ show $a$ is not an accumulation point of their zeros. @gary

Comment: @gary which weierstrass theorem you mean?

Comment: @Leviathan: Every bounded infinite subset of Euclidean space has a limit point ( within the subset). Consider then the  collection of  balls $B(0,n); n=1,2,....$ , all finite. If  S is uncountable, one of those balls will  contain infinitely-many points, and therefore, by Weirstrass, a limit point.