# let $f$ be a complex valued function. if $f$ has uncountable number of singularity. Then is it true that $f$ must have non isolated singularity ??

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity, singularity

let $f$ be a complex valued function. if $f$ has uncountable number of singularity.

Then is it true that $f$ must have non isolated singularity ??

I think it is true . but have no idea how to prove this.

Any idea. Thanks

Comment: Isn't there a theorem which says that every bounded infinite set has a limit point?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/962314/42969 – that is about poles, but the same arguments apply to arbitrary types of singularities.

Answer (score 1):

This has  nothing to do with Complex Analysis. Any uncountable set in an Euclidean space has a limit point. This is because the points in the set at distance at most $n$ from the origin must be an infinite set for some $n$; any bounded infinite set has a limit point.