# If a function is meromorphic on a ball, the set of poles is finite

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, meromorphic-functions

Let $X$ be a normed space, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb C$ be open and $f:\Omega\to X$ be meromorphic in the sense that for all $z_0\in\Omega$, there is a $k_{z_0}\in\mathbb N_0$, $\left(a^{(z_0)}_k\right)_{k\ge-k_{z_0}}\subseteq X$ and a neighborhood $N_{z_0}\subseteq\Omega$ of $z_0$ with $$f(z)=\underbrace{\sum_{k=-k_{z_0}}^{-1}a_k^{(z_0)}(z-z_0)^k}_{=:\:m_{z_0}(z)}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k^{(z_0)}(z-z_0)^k}_{=:\:h_{z_0}(z)}\tag1$$ for all $z\in N_{z_0}\setminus\{z_0\}$. Let $P$ denote the subset of $\Omega$ for which $k_{z_0}$ cannot be chosen to be $0$.

> Let $B\subseteq\Omega$ be bounded. According to comments by [Martin R](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r) below a previous version of this question, $F:=B\cap P$ is only finite, when $\overline B\subseteq\Omega$. *Why*?

I really tried to understand this, but I don't. First of all, discretness is a hereditary property of a topological space and hence there is no difference between $P$ being "discrete in $\Omega$" or "discrete in $\mathbb C$".

To make sure, we talk about the same concepts: Let $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space and $\mathcal N_\tau(x):=\{N\subseteq E:N\text{ is a }\tau\text{-neighborhood of }x\}$ for $x\in E$. Then,

- $B\subseteq E$ is called $\tau$-discrete if $\left.\tau\right|_B$ is the discrete topology on $D$;
- $x\in E$ is called $\tau$-isolated point of $B\subseteq E$ if $$\exists N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):B\cap N=\{x\};$$
- $x\in E$ is called $\tau$-accumulation point of $B\subseteq E$ if $$\forall N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):B\cap N\setminus\{x\}\ne\emptyset.$$

If $x\in E$ and $A\subseteq B\subseteq E$, it is straightforward to show that

1. if $x\in A$ and $x$ is an $\tau$-isolated point of $B$, then $x$ is an $\tau$-isolated point of $A$;
2. $x$ is an $\left.\tau\right|_B$-isolated point of $A$ iff $x$ is an $\tau$-isolated point of $A$;
3. $x\in E$ is an $\tau$-isolated point of $B$ iff $$\{x\}\in\left.\tau\right|_B;$$
4. $B$ is $\tau$-discrete iff every point in $B$ is an $\tau$-isolated point of $B$;
5. if $x$ is an $\tau$-accumulation point of $A$, then $x$ is an $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$;
6. $x$ is an $\left.\tau\right|_B$-accumulation point of $A$ iff $x$ is an $\tau$-accumulation point of $A$;
7. $B$ is $\tau$-discrete iff $D\cap K$ is finite for every $\tau$-compact $K\subseteq E$;
8. Each point in $B$ is either a $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$ or an $\tau$-isolated point of $B$.

> From (7.), it should immediately follow that $P\cap\overline B$ is finite, since $\overline B$ is clearly compact (which, by the way, is a hereditary property as well). But if $P\cap\overline B$ is finite, then clearly $F=P\cap B$ is finite as well.
>
> What am I missing?

**EDIT**: The example $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<1\}$ and $P=\left\{1-\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\right\}$, provided in the comments below, shows that something about (7.) seems actually to be wrong. But which of my assertions is wrong?

Proof of "$\Rightarrow$" in (7.): Let $K\subseteq E$ be $\tau$-compact and assume $D\cap K$ is infinite. Since $(K,\left.\tau\right|_K)$ is [limit point compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point_compact), $D\cap K$ has a $\left.\tau\right|_K$-accumulation point $x$. By (5.) and (6.), $x$ is an $\tau$-accumulation point of $D$. Thus, by (8.), $x$ is not an $\tau$-isolated point of $D$; in contradiction to (4.).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118813/discussion-on-question-by-0xbadf00d-if-a-function-is-meromorphic-on-a-ball-the).

Comment: Something seems off : let's take $\Omega$ as the unit disk and $D = \{1- \frac 1n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ as Martin did. Now, Take a compact set $K$ as the closed disk of radius half. Now, $D$ is discrete , because the condition of 3. and 4. being satisfied. So $K \cap D$ should be finite, but it is *not*. So there's an issue with the $\implies$ part of 7. Looking deeper, $D \cap K$ does not have an accumulation point. In fact, no subset of a discrete set has an accumulation point. That I can explain, but please see that there is an issue here.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I really wish to answer your question, not only because you have placed a bounty on it but because I think you have been detailed and meticulous with your presentation and hence deserve an answer. But for that , I wish to converse with you. I have not received a reply to what I wrote yesterday, and I need one to move the conversation forward, otherwise your question will stagnate.