# Finite sum over uncountable set

Tags: summation, cardinals

Consider the sum $S=\sum_{x\in I}P(x)$, where $P(x)$ are positive real numbers. When the index set $I$ is finite, $S$ is of course finite. When $I$ is countably infinite, it is also possible that $S$ is finite. For example $\sum_{x\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^x}$. Is it true that $S$ cannot be finite if $I$ is uncountable?

Comment: How do you define the sum in that case? Note that even the countable case is not really a sum any longer, but a limit of partial sums.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers

Comment: Unless $P(x)$ is zero for all but countably many terms, then I know of no good way to make sense of such a sum (over an uncountable index set).