# How to show this subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a finite set $X$, we write $\sum X$ to be the sum of all the numbers in $X$. Suppose we have a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $-100\le \sum X \le 100$ for all finite subsets $X \subseteq S$. How to show that $S$ is countable?

I do not really know where to begin. Hints would be nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For each $n\in\mathbb N$ consider the sets
$$ S\cap(-\infty,-1/n) \quad\text{and}\quad S\cap(1/n,\infty) $$
There are countably many of these sets, and their union is $S\setminus\{0\}$.
How large can each of them be?

Comment: Where do you get that each set is finite?

Comment: @ElliotG: Imagine what happens $S\cap (1/n,\infty)$ has at least $100n$ elements ...

Comment: I'm not seeing how we can say anything about $S\cap (1/n,\infty)$. How do we know it isn't uncountable. Even if it is finite, the sum could still be zero.

Comment: @ElliotG: How can a sum of $100n$ elements of $(1/n,\infty)$ be zero?

Comment: Ok I see your point there. Still not seeing how this proves $S\cap (1/n,\infty)$ is countable thought

Comment: @ElliotG: Are you trying in a roundabout way to assert that I should have said "finite or countable" instead of "countable"? I'm confused, because my answer uses _neither_ of the words "finite" or "countable" about $S\cap (1/n,\infty)$ but instead leaves it to the reader to draw conclusions about it, with whatever terminology he prefers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38240/discussion-between-elliot-g-and-henning-makholm).

Answer (score 0):

This is strongly related to [The sum of an uncountable number of positive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20661/238069). Using this you know that all but countably many elements of S are 0. Since 0 appears at most once you are done.