# How to prove a result regarding summation on infinite sets.

Tags: analysis, summation

Prove that if ($X$ can be uncountable)$$M:=\sup\bigg{\{}\sum_{x\in X}|f(x)|:A\subseteq X, A \ \text{finite}\bigg\} < \infty $$
then the sets $\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geq{1}/{n} \}$ are finite with cardinality at most $nM$ for all positive integers n.
Where do I begin ? Why this result should be true ?

Comment: What happens if you add *more than* $nM$ numbers together, each of which is at least $1/n$?

Comment: This seems to be basically the same question as
[The sum of an uncountable number of positive numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/20661). See also other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20661).

Comment: BTW I guess $\sum\limits_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ (inside the supremum) is a typo and you wanted to write $\sum\limits_{x\in A}|f(x)|$. (In fact, one of possible definitions of $\sum\limits_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ is to definite it as supremum of sums over finite subsets.)