# Infinite Union/Intersection vs Infinite summation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I have a question for you.

It's well known that I can't sum an infinite number of "number". Indeed, the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k
$$
is defined as a Limit.

However, I can make the infinite union/intersection of sets. Someone can explain me why ?

Comment: I am not sure why you can't sum an infinite number of terms (other than summing them one by one of course).  But if $a_i = 0$ for all $i$, then the sum is $0$ ... no limit needed.

Comment: The reason is that the sets are defined by its elements... then if you have a rule, that symbolically can be seen as an infinite intersection, you only need to care if the elements belong to the set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets are not real numbers. They are part of a much larger universe. The real numbers are bound by $\Bbb R$, they all have to be members of $\Bbb R$, and the summation has to obey the rules of summations which extend addition (under the usual definition of a sum, that is).

On the other hand, an infinite family of sets is itself just a set of sets. One of the axioms of set theory tells us that given a set $A$ of sets—finite, countable, uncountable, *any* set—we can take the union of all the sets in $A$.

Answer (score 6):

Take this as the definition of infinite unions and intersections:

$x \in A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \dots $ if and only if $x \in A_i$ for at least one $i \in \mathbb N$.

$x \in A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \dots $ if and only if $x \in A_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$.

This makes perfect sense as it is. There is no need for a limiting procedure.

(In fact, there is even no need to assume that there are countably many $A_i$'s...)

The reason that sum of a series is different is that we define it inductively. Say we're trying to work out
$$ a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4\dots $$
Well, let $S_i$ be the sum of the first $i$ terms. Then you *define*
$$ S_1 = a_1, \ \ \ \ S_2 = S_1+ a_2, \ \ \ \ S_3 = S_2 + a_3, \ \ \ \ S_4 = S_3 + a_4, \dots $$

But the problem with this is that, no matter how many steps you do, you will never reach $S_\infty$. This is why summing infinite series requires a special procedure.

Comment: Really helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am not sure why you can't sum an infinite number of terms (other than summing them one by one of course). If $a_i = 0$ for all $i$, then the sum is $0$ ... no limit needed.

But yes, typically we have to use a limit to evaluate the value of the sum.

The difference with sets is that we are not *evaluating* anything ... we are simply defining what the elements of the union or intersection are.

Answer (score -1):

The countable intersection and union are also limits. $$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_n$$

Set operations can be defined without reference to the size of the domain of "summation": $$\bigcup A := \{ x: x \in X \in A \}$$
$$\bigcap A := \{x : (\forall X \in A)(x \in x) \}$$
(no countability needed).

Note that infinite sums are only really defined when the domain of summation is countable (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers)). So infinite sums are really very restricted objects compared to sets.

Comment: You're wrong. There is no limit involved in the definition of infinite union of sets. What you mean by "limit"? There's no a notion of distance between a set as in the real numbers

Comment: @GianmarcoVidotto This was the notation in the measure theory course I attended, but I'm happy to make it more handwavy if you like.

Comment: If you treat the word "limit" informally for a moment, do you agree that there is only one remotely plausible definition for $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ where $X_1 \subseteq X_2 \subseteq \dots$?

Comment: I knew it! These are standard definitions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: This has now got a delete vote and three downvotes, but nobody has told me why it's wrong. Please tell me in what way I've misunderstood the Wikipedia link!