# Number of nonzero Fourier coefficients for any $x$ can be at most countably many

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have been trying to prove Lemma 3.5 in "Introduction to Functional Analysis" by Kreyszig, which says that:

*Any $x$ in an inner product space $X$ can have at most countably many nonzero Fourier coefficients $\langle x,e_k\rangle$ with respect to an orthonormal family $(e_k), k\in I,$ in X.*

This is my attempt at proof using the hint provided in the book:

Let $n_m$ be the number of Fourier coefficients which are greater than $1/m$. By Bessel inequality:
$$\|x\|^2\geq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\big|\langle x,e_k\rangle\big|^2> n_m\frac{1}{m^2}.$$
$$\implies n_m< m^2\|x\|^2. $$
This last inequality is clearly true for any $m=1,2,....$. Which implies that maximum number of nonzero Fourier coefficients $n_{\frac{1}{\infty}}<\infty.$

But I am stuck here. It is clear that number of nonzero coefficients might be infinite, but how does it imply $n_m$ is still countable.

The same question has been asked at: [Fourier coefficients $\langle x,e_k\rangle$ are at countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274906/fourier-coefficients-langle-x-e-k-rangle-are-at-countable). But I don't understand the last sentence of the answer: Therefore there are only countably many i with $|\langle x,e_i\rangle|>0.$

Comment: Each $n_m$ is **finite**. I can't see what you mean by $n_{\frac1\infty}$.

Comment: I have seen that question. But I don't understand the last sentence of the answer:
Therefore there are only countably many i with $|\langle x,e_i\rangle|>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{k:\langle x,e_k \rangle \neq 0\}$ is the union of the sets $\{k:|\langle x,e_k \rangle| > 1/n\}$ over all positive integers n. Each of the sets in the union is finite (as you have shown) and countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Thanks! it is helpful. I missed the point that countable union of countable collection of sets is countable.