# Looking for a reference (textbook) for an elementary analysis problem on uncountable sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation

A well-known problem in elementary real analysis is to show that no uncountable sum of positive real numbers can be finite (this requires a precise formulation, but that would take me too far afield). I believe I saw this problem myself in a textbook as an undergraduate or grad student. If anyone has a reference (if a textbook, edition number and page number would be helpful; I would expect this to appear as a problem in several real/functional analysis texts), I would be quite grateful. Thank you!

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that this problem appeared on this site several times. See [The sum of an uncountable number of positive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20661) and some of [the posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20661).

Comment: See also this post (which is a reference request, too): [Series on Infinite Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424712)

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent problem appears as Exercise 0.0.1 on page xii of Terence Tao's *An Introduction to Measure Theory*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question occurs in W. Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" as an exercise at the end of the first chapter.

I do give it as an exercise in real analysis, with a "solution"/discussion, e.g., in the first set of examples/discussions at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/real/

Answer (score 1):

You can look in Folland's Real Analysis 2e, Chapter 0.