# Any Meromorphic function can at most have a countable number of poles.

Tags: complex-analysis

I can prove this: Any Meromorphic function $f$  can at most have a countable number of poles.

With use of:
[The sum of an uncountable number of positive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers)

Any pole a is contained in $B(a,r)$ some $r>0$ small.  For all $a,b$ poles, $B(a,r)\cap B(b,r)=\emptyset$ some $r>0$ small. if i could prove that $\bigcup_{a\, pole} B(a,r)\subset B(0,R)$ some $R>0$ then $Area(\bigcup_{a\, pole} B(a,r))=\sum_{a\, pole} Area(B(a,r))<\infty$.
Then, $Area(B(a,r))=0$ except for some countable many with $Area(B(a,r))>0$. Therefore the poles of $f$  can at most have a countable number of poles.
This is correct?

Question 1.Why exists $B(0,R)$ such that $\bigcup_{a\, pole} B(a,r)\subset B(0,R)$ some $R>0$ big?

Question 2. If $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ meromorphic function has an infinite countable number of poles. The poles accumulate on the border of region $G$? Why?

Comment: Why so complicated? Each of the (disjoint)  $B(a,r)$ contains a point with rational coordinates, and there are at most countably many rational pairs.

Comment: oh right! it is more simply

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1.Why exists $B(0,R)$ such that $\bigcup_{a\, pole} B(a,r)\subset B(0,R)$ some $R>0$ big?

That is not true. If the domain is unbounded then the poles can accumulate at infinity. Example: $f(z) = 1/\sin(z)$.

But each of the (disjoint)  $B(a,r)$ contains a point with rational coordinates, and there are at most countably many rational pairs.

> Question 2. If $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ meromorphic function has an infinite countable number of poles. The poles accumulate on the border of region $G$? Why?

First note that the poles can not accumulate at a point $a \in G$: Otherwise there is a sequence $(z_n)$ of poles with $z_n \ne a$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} z_n = a$. But $f$ is either holomorphic at $z_0$ or has an (isolated) pole at $a$. In both cases there is a $r > 0$ such that $f$ is holomorphic in $B(a,r)\setminus \{a\}$, i.e. $B(a,r)$ contains no poles except possibly $a$. This is a contradiction.

Now assume that $f$ has infinitely many poles:

- If the set of poles is *bounded* then it must have an accumulation point in $\Bbb C$ (that is the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem). As we saw above, the accumulation point cannot be in $G$, and therefore must be on the boundary of $G$.
- If the set of poles is *unbounded* then the poles accumulate at $\infty$. This is also boundary point of $G$ in the extended complex plane.

One can also consider $G$ as a subset of the [extended complex plane](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Extended_complex_plane) $\hat{ \Bbb C}$ with the chordal metric. That is a compact metric space so that every sequence has a convergent subsequence. In particular, the sequence of poles has an accumulation point in the closure $\overline G$, and since the poles can not accumulate in $G$, the every accumulation point is on $\partial G$.

Comment: But is it possible that the poles never accumulate? or specifically will they accumulate on the bundary of G?

Comment: If the function has infinitely many poles the they must accumulate (at the boundary).

Comment: If $f$ has an pole at $ z_0$ then $f$ is holomorphic in $B(z_0,r)\setminus \left\{z_0\right\}.$ This implies that  $B(z_0,r)\setminus \left\{z_0\right\}$  contain poles differents of  $z_0$ because $z_0$ is a accumulation point but this is a contradiction because the poles are aislated. This is correct? Same argument when $f$ is analytic in $z_0$.In any case, I cannot see the contradiction clearly with the fact $z_0\in G$

Comment: If the function has infinitely many poles the they must accumulate (at the boundary).
This is a knows results?

Comment: @eraldcoil: I have extended the answer. Please let me know if something is still unclear.