# Proof that if unordered sum is finite, then there are finitely many positive terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I'm confused about a statement I've seen.

For $\{c_{i} : i \in I\}$, and $P = \{i \in I : c_{i} > 0\}$ it states:

$\sum_{i \in I} c_{i} < \infty \implies $P countable

I understand this is true intuitively but I don't know how you'd formulate the proof for it.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers) is related

Comment: Is $u_i=c_i$ ??

Comment: @mathPhys a nice proof is given in the question to the above link

Comment: @lulu $I$ is some indexing set. $P$ is the set of strictly positive elements of $\{c_{i} : i \in I\}$

Comment: I've corrected my mistake now @Fred.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMelech thats very helpful

Comment: @mathPhys You're welcome!