# Can the sum of all elements of a continuous, finite set of real numbers be expressed as an infinite sum of distinct numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I'm a high-school math student, and I recently stumbled upon an interesting, but counterintuitive result while solving a problem. I was trying to prove that the sum **$S$ of all $x$ such that $x\in(0,1)$** was not finite. While doing so, I found this:

Using **divide-and-conquer** approach, $$\begin{aligned} S &= \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4}  \right) + \left( \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{8} + \frac{5}{8} + \frac{7}{8} \right) + ...\infty
\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{2^{i-1}} \frac{2j-1}{2^i} \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2^{i-1})^2}{2^i} \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 2^{i-2} \\ &= \frac{1}{2} + 1 +2 + 4 + 8 +...\infty \end{aligned} $$
Is this valid or is there a flaw that I'm missing?

Comment: I am aware of that. However, isn't this a geometric series? I understand that both the series are divergent and consequently, their summation tends to infinity. My question here is that can a summation of continuous elements be seen equivalently as the sum of distinct elements?

Comment: One thorn is [how to define the sum of uncountably many addends](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers). But your argument is fine: since the numbers are nonnegative, any reasonable definition of the full sum should be larger than the sum over a countable subset, and you've found one such subset that diverges.

Comment: Well, in that all these infinite sums diverge to infinity, I guess you could say this is correct.

Comment: I’m not sure I know how you are using the term “continuous element” here.

Comment: By the way, we don’t tend to put $\infty$ at the end of infinite sums like this.

Comment: I apologize, Mr. Andrews, I actually meant to write "sum of elements of a continuous, finite set of real numbers" :-)

Comment: And as for the convention of $\infty$ at the end of sums, I must admit I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Maybe a bit simpler: $$\left(\frac13+\frac23\right)+\left(\frac14+\frac34\right)+\left(\frac15+\frac45\right)+\cdots=1+1+1+\cdots=\infty$$

Comment: That's nice 

Comment: I think "continuous, finite set" is a contradiction in terms, at any rate if you are using those mathy terms the way mathematicians use them. Maybe you have your own, private meanings for those words, that you'd like to share with us?

Comment: I actually realised that all such sets are actually infinite. I understand what you mean to say, Mr. Myerson. Careless of me.

Comment: I apologise. What I'm referring to are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such as $[0,2)$ or $(-12,3)$ but not ones like $(-\infty, 6)$ or $(3.5, \infty)$. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Those are called "finite intervals", but a "finite **set**" is a set that contains a finite number of points.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, Upayan, you have to put @Gerry in it. That way, I get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that your summation is correct. Your summation consists only of non-recurring rational numbers, so clearly many terms are being missed, i.e., all irrational and rational numbers with recurring decimal expansion.