# A question from ISI MMath PMB on analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The following is a question from ISI MMath PMB.I want to know whether the proof is correct.

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ be a function.Assume that there is $M\geq 0$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k f(x_i)\leq M,\forall k\geq 1$ and $\forall x_1,...,x_k\in [0,1]$.Show that $\{x|f(x)\neq 0\}$ is countable.

Proof:Let $A=\{x|f(x)\neq 0\}=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty\{x:f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$

Let $A_k=\{x|f(x)\geq \frac{1}{k}\}$ be infinite,for some $k\in \mathbb N$.

Then $A_n$ is infinite for all $n\geq k$.

Take a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq k}$ such that $f(x_n)\geq \frac{1}{n}$  and $x_n\in A_n$

Then $\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty f(x_n)$ diverges.

Thus we have a contradiction that assures that each $A_n$ is finite,hence $A$ is countable.

Comment: I think this is correct and essentially the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers).

Comment: @Kishalay how did you get the intuition to go ahead with the proof? I am also preparing for ISI while going through this year's paper I saw the question but the solution didn't strike me

Comment: @Antimony it depends on practice