# Integral symbol in linear combination decomposition of function

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, notation

## Sequences:

I like to see a sequence $(u_n) \in \mathbb K ^{\mathbb N}$ as: $$(u_n) = \sum_0^{\infty}  u_i\times (e_i)$$

where $u_i$ is $i$-ish term of the sequence and $(e_i)$ are the sequences such as $$(e_0)=(1, 0, 0, ...)$$

$$(e_1)= (0,1,0, ...)$$

## Functions:

In complete analogy, I'd like do the same with a function $f\in \mathbb K ^{\mathbb R}$

$$f =  \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e_x$$

where $e_x$ :

$$
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
\text{if $t=x$ }&1\\
\text{if $t\neq x$}&0
\end{array}
\right\}
=e_x (t)
$$

and $f(x)$ is the value of $f$ at $x$

My question is: is it valid to use the integral sign in this definition? I am used to see this integral symbol with the $dx$ symbol. That's why I ask.

Comment: what is $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: $\mathbb K$ is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$

Comment: The first problem is that you have not defined with respect to what it is that you are integrating . Integration is done wrt some measure. So what you need is the Dirac measure at $x$  That is take $\delta_{x}(A)=1$ if $A$ contains $x$ and $0$ otherwise. with this you can actually define $f(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}} f(x)\,d\delta_{x}$

Comment: I think what you need is an "uncountable sum", such as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers