# Finding a finite subset from an uncountable set of positive real numbers, such that the sum of elements exceeds 2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am not sure how to go about this problem: Let $A$ be an uncountable set of positive real numbers. Show that there exists a finite subset of numbers from $A$ whose sum is larger than $2$.

By the [Archimedean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) property, we get a positive integer $n$ such that $nx > 2$ for $x$ in $A$. But I am not sure how to get a finite subset from $A$ such that the elements' sum will be greater than $2$. Please help!

Comment: There is no positive integer $n$ such that $nx>2$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ (it doesn’t work for $x=1/n$).

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20661/42969, and  this comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers#comment44926_20661

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $n\ge 1$, consider the subset of elements of $A$ greater than $1/n$: $A_n = \{x\in A: x > 1/n\}$. Clearly $A$ is equal to the countable union $\bigcup_n A_n$. Since $A$ is uncountable by hypothesis, what can you conclude?

Comment: Is it the fact that at least one of the An's will be uncountable?

Comment: @EmranHossen: Right, once you know that one of the $A_n$'s is uncountable, what can you conclude?

Comment: So we get an uncountable subset of A such that x >1/n for some n, for all x in that uncountable subset.

Comment: @EmranHossen: correct, and how does that allow you to finish your proof?

Comment: Is it because we can pick 2n elements such that $x1+x2+...+x_(2n) > 1/n +1/n + ... 1/n = 2n*(1/n) = 2$? So our finite set is {x1,x2,...,x_(2n)}.

Comment: @EmranHossen: Done!